# Shrink children to fit in Row

Tags: user-interface, layout, flutter, constraints, overflow

I have made some simple custom Widget in flutter that only have a aspect ratio constraint, something like this:

```
Container(
  child: AspectRatio(
    aspectRation: 1.0,
    child: item != null
              ? Image.asset("assets/...")
              : Container(),
  ),
)
```

This widget is empty if no item and loads an image if the item is set. I just want it to be square and want the size to be limited by the parent.

Then I put 3 to 5 of these in a Row that is in a Container. I limit the Containers height to become a bar in the top of my app. This makes the widgets inside get limited by my height and it works fine if I have 3 widgets in the row. But if I put 5, my row will get overflowed (to wide). This of course because it makes them also 100 wide because of the aspect ratio and 5 times 100 is too much for my UI. What I really would want is for my widgets height to be MAXIMUM 100 pixels, but only if they still fit the width of my Row. Otherwise I want them to shrink but still keep the aspect ratio. How can I do this?

Here is a small code example, if I put the items to 5 they fill up the entire row and stay square. But with 3 as now, the borders of the items stretch and fill all the row (not respecting the aspect ratio):

```
  Widget _buildCompBar(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
        height: 100,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: List<Widget>.filled(
            3,
            Expanded(
              child: AspectRatio(
                aspectRatio: 1.0,
                child: Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(width: 2),
                    borderRadius: new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                  ),
                  child:
                      Image.asset("assets/images/mons/unit_icon_0000_0_0.png"),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
```

So in short, in the example, if enough items, they shrink to fit. But if too few items to fill the row, the empty space gets added INSIDE the items instead of between them...

Also tried with the image as decoration and then the while image fills the entire row. Can't make it keep its square shape either with AspectRatio nor FittedBox:

```
  Widget _buildCompBar(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
      height: 100,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,

        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: AspectRatio(
              aspectRatio: 1.0,
              child:
                  Container(
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          border: Border.all(width: 2),
                          borderRadius:
                              new BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
                          shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
                          image: new DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            image: AssetImage("assets/images/mons/unit_icon_0000_0_0.png"),
                          ))),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

I feel it behaved much differently with the image as a decoration, I imagine there is no constraints at all for that container then. However the border looks much better like that (no white space around the image), so I would really like to solve it with the decoration image.

Comment: I tried putting Expanded around my items, that kinda worked for the 5 items in a row, but the 3 gets stretched to fill the whole width...

Comment: What about using a `Spacer` Widget instead of an empty container for the widgets that don't have and item assigned?

Comment: Ah, not sure what will be the difference, but I will try it right away...

Comment: Doesn't really work, I just get an exception:

`I/flutter ( 4129): The following assertion was thrown building Spacer:`
`I/flutter ( 4129): Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget.`
`I/flutter ( 4129): Expanded widgets must be placed directly inside Flex widgets.`


But also, it is not really the problem, I also get the same behavior when I have placed items (images) inside the boxes. If Expanded the border gets stretched, if not, five items wont fit.

Comment: All I want is a row with 3 to 5 perfectly square items that expand to fit the height while keeping their aspect ratio. Is that too much to ask? :)

Comment: This is completely impossible, I have tried every combination imaginable with Container, Expanded, FittedBox, there is always some problem (overflowing, shrinking too much etc). I really need help...

Comment: Could it be that Expanded doesn't respect AspectRatio at all?